# Why I can't mine eth in my private network?

Tags: go-ethereum

Mist Version: 0.10.0 OS & Version: windows/64 Node version: geth 8.11.1

Screen shot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqGsO.jpg

I've created a private network all fine but when I attache and miner.start(1); the kh/s show in Mist but I keep waiting and no ether got mine not a single one!!!

https://codeshare.io/GqxZ3Z this is the code of the first command line where I start geth

https://codeshare.io/2pgZYX this is the second terminal where I start mining command

I think the ERROR 'The pipe is being closed' it's the problem and that happen when opening Mist, see line 18 in the code in the first command line snippet, help! thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

As I see on the last screenshot, **the eth.mine() function doesn't give you any error**. You only started 1 thread of your processor but that doesn't mean that it's not working fine.

If the config of your chain isn't correct, your genesis block difficulty is too high or the HashRate power or your machine is so low, It can cause that your block generation may last about 15 to 30 minutes per block or even more.

So i recommend you to create the blockchain again, and set a much lower difficulty in order to make the difficulty calculation algorithm adaptation grow progressively, not set it too high because you won't mine the first block never.

[Here](https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0) you have a tutorial to do it which is quite well done.

Hope it helps!